Is there a way to canonicalize time zone IDs using the java.time APIs?
Some time zones are aliases for other time zones. For example, at the time of writing, Europe/Skopje and Europe/Zagreb are linked to Europe/Belgrade.
In Joda Time, these aliases can be resolved by using DateTimeZone.forID(id).getID(), since DateTimeZone.forID() follows these links to return the canonical time zone.
Is it possible to do something similar with the java.time APIs?
Some things I've tried:

ZoneId.of(id) will throw an exception if the ID does not exist, but will not resolve links: ZoneId.of("Europe/Skopje").getId() returns "Europe/Skopje", not "Europe/Belgrade".

ZoneId.of(id).normalized() only canonicalizes fixed-offset time zones, so does nothing useful here that I can see.

All these time zones are returned by ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds(), and it's possible to ask for each one's rules via ZoneId.getRules(), so given that the rules will be equal for a canonical zone and all linked zones, it's possible to identify that, say, Europe/Belgrade, Europe/Skopje, and Europe/Zagreb are all equivalent, but not to work out which one is canonical. (I'm also not completely sure that it's necessarily true that having equal rules means that the two time zones are necessary linked.)



Looking at TzdbZoneRulesProvider.class, the links between the zone IDs are non-public, so probably not.
